# How do I set up Apache HTTP authorization with a salt in my password?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, password, encryption

I'm using [`mod_auth_mysql`](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/) with Apache 2 and MySQL 5 for apache authorization. Right now our passwords are being stored in the plain in our database. As a new requirement, we have to store them with a salt, to fight rainbow table attacks. The documentation states:

```
AuthMySQLSaltField <> | <string> | mysql_column_name

 Contains information on the salt field to be used for crypt and aes
 encryption methods.  It can contain one of the following:
   <>: password itself is the salt field (use with crypt() only)
   <string>: "string" as the salt field
   mysql_column_name: the salt is take from the mysql_column_name field in the
     same row as the password

 This field is required for aes encryption, optional for crypt encryption.
 It is ignored for all other encryption types.
```

So it looks like the module can do it, but I can't find anything on how to do this? What should I put in the password column? What should I put in the salt? How do I use AES? (Most of the applications will be PHP for creating users)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what your salt is!

Generally, you might use something that the user can't change, like their ID, as a salt; if that is the case, specify the column that contains the user ID.

If you are using a constant salt, then enclose it in <> marks.

Comment: I wouldn't use a username for a salt, not to start any crypto wars, but if you can just use another random string stored in another column, there's no reason for not so random/possibly malicious user input to be in there.

Comment: I meant a numeric ID - MediaWiki, for example, stores the password as the hash of '#-password', where # is your user ID. See http://xoa.petdance.com/How_to:_Reset_a_MediaWiki_password

Answer (score 0):

The salt should be a random string not a md5/sha1/256. The docs you presented are looking for the salt to be in it's own column. So you "need" 3 Columns for auth uses

```
Usersname/email = user submitted
passwordhash = hash(password, passwordsalt)
passwordsalt = random string
```

You can easily use these columns to verify passwords and create new user records with salt and hash.

Don't ever store plain text passwords.

As for the hash() function, take a look at the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library. It's what wordpress turned to when they finally implimented salted hashes in their database.

Comment: so what's the hash function in PHP that I use here?

Comment: Here's a blog post with a summary I think mod_auth_mysql can use more then md5 these days. http://funkatron.com/site/comments/encouraging-steps-towards-security-in-wordpress-25/